# while a regex match do something

Tags: python, regex

I want to parse a file and when a pattern match continue to test the regex. Because I want to work on the return value I've wrote:

```
while (m=test.match(data)) != None:
    pass
```

In my idea, I want to affect `m` to `test.match(data)` and after test if is None or not. But with this syntax I have :

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

How can I write this without SyntaxError?

Comment: I suspect You are using the wrong function for this task. Use `search()` not `match()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use assignment in loop clause:

```
m = test.match(data)
if not m:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can't do assignments in a while loop in any language where it expects a condition.

I suspect you are trying to scan through your file to match for patterns and then use them later. In that case `match()` is not the correct function. IMHO

```
variable = "123abc"
t = re.match("[a-z]+",variable) //returns null as word not in the beginning
t = re.search("[a-z]+",variable) // matches as it scans through
```